# Python C API PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords fails on second function call

Tags: python, python-2.7, c++17, python-c-api

I'm currently facing a weird problem with python c api. It only happens on 1 machine, I can't reproduce the error on other machines.

On the second call (`b=...`) I get the error `fail secondary argument 1 must be string, not tuple`.
If i pass only `False` instead of `asynchronous=False` as the fourth argument of the second call for `b` the code works without an error.

The first call always succeeds. If i swap both calls it stays the same (First succeeds, second fails). What could be the issue?

python code:

```
    try:
        print("connecting server 1")
        a = XRPythonOPC.Startup("Matrikon.OPC.Simulation.1","","{F8582CF2-88FB-11D0-B850-00C0F0104305}", asynchronous=False)
    except Exception as e:
      print("Failed to connect opc python servers1 ")
    try:
            print("connecting server 2")
            b = XRPythonOPC.Startup("Softing.OPCToolbox.C++.Sample.Demo.DA.1","","{5B5EBB5B-706E-404E-93D5-72A77212A14B}", asynchronous=False)   
    except Exception as e:
       print("Failed to connect 2")
```

Python C API Code (C++):

```
static PyObject* Startup(PyTypeObject* /*type*/, PyObject* args, PyObject* keywds)
{
   const char*  ServerName = "";
   const char*  NodeName   = "";
   const char*  ClsID      = "";
   PyObject*    Async      = Py_True;
   
   static char* kwlist[]   = { "server_name", "node", "clsid", "asynchronous", NULL };

// fails here
   if (!PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(args, keywds, "|sssO", (kwlist), &ServerName, &NodeName, &ClsID, &Async))
   {
     return NULL;
   }

   PyObject* obj = PyObject_Call(reinterpret_cast<PyObject*>(&XRPythonOPCType), args, keywds);
   
   return obj;
}

static int Init(XRPythonOPC* self, PyObject* args, PyObject* keywds)
{
   static char* kwlist[]   = { "server_name", "node", "clsid", "asynchronous", NULL };

   const char*  ServerName = "";
   const char*  NodeName   = "";
   const char*  ClsID      = "";
   //int         Async      = 1;
   PyObject*    Async      = Py_True;


   if (!PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(args, keywds, "|sssO", (kwlist), &ServerName, &NodeName, &ClsID, &Async))
   {
     PyErr_SetString(PyExc_RuntimeError, "Either server_name or clsid needs to be provided to connect to a server or failed to parse arguments");
  
     return -1;
   }

   // Set Server, Node, Clsid, Async
   ///...
   //
  return 0;

}
```

When printing the types inside of Startup gives me `tupleiterator, str, str,str`. But shouldn't that be str,str,str,bool ?

I also made sure that i have the same python version on all machines.

```
      PyObject*    iterator   = PyObject_GetIter(args);
      PyObject*    Item = iterator;
      if (iterator)
     {
        //Item = PyIter_Next(iterator);
        while (Item != nullptr)
        {
          std::wcout << XRPyStringAsWstring(PyObject_GetAttrString((PyObject*)(Py_TYPE(Item)), "__name__"))
                     << std::endl;
         Item = PyIter_Next(iterator);
       }
     }
```